# django-admin-bootstrapped messing with DateField, TimeField and PointField

Tags: javascript, python, twitter-bootstrap, django-admin, postgis

I've just added django-admin-bootstrapped to my project. Almost everything is fine. 
Actually there are two little bug whitch i'm wondering how to resolve.
The first one is about DateField and TimeField : There is no date/time picker when i'm under django-admin-bootstrapped. When i check the source code, there is no generated source code about the two picker. When i deactivate django-admin-bootstrapped, here is what is missing :

> Next to the DateField :

```
<span class="datetimeshortcuts">&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleCalendarQuickLink(0, 0);">Today</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.openCalendar(0);"
    id="calendarlink0"><img src="/static/admin/img/icon_calendar.gif" alt="Calendar">
</a></span>
```

> Next to the TimeField :

```
<span class="datetimeshortcuts">&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(1, -1);">Now</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.openClock(1);" 
    id="clocklink1"><img src="/static/admin/img/icon_clock.gif" alt="Clock">
</a></span>
```

The second one is about a PointField (i'm working with postGis), without django-admin-bootstrapped, my field is fine, but when it's bootstrapped, i have an error onto OpenLayer.js :

```
OpenLayers.js:679 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'w' of null
```

So, two questions (using django 1.8 and django-admin-bootstrapped):

> 1- How to recover a date/time picker in the admin interface ?
>   2- How to recover my PointField map picker in the admin interface ?

Thank's all of you. (Here the same issue (1) on github : https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped/issues/168 but there is only external workarround (and i prefer a nativ one))

---

EDIT : From my sitepackage : ./django/contrib/gis/admin/options.py
I've directly changed the line who call OpenLayer.js to OpenLayer.debug.js to provide you more information.

> In OpenLayer.debug.js line 40008 is the source of the error :

```
setMap: function(map) {        
    OpenLayers.Layer.prototype.setMap.apply(this, arguments);

    if (!this.renderer) {
        this.map.removeLayer(this);
    } else {
        this.renderer.map = this.map;

        var newSize = this.map.getSize();
40008-> newSize.w = newSize.w * this.ratio;
        newSize.h = newSize.h * this.ratio;
        this.renderer.setSize(newSize);
    }
},
```

Here the entire JS traceback on OpenLayer.debug.js + index of GeoDjango:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'w' of null ==> OpenLayers.debug.js:40008

```
newSize.w = newSize.w * this.ratio;
```

OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.OpenLayers.Class.setMap ==> OpenLayers.debug.js:8349

```
layer.setMap(this);
```

OpenLayers.Map.OpenLayers.Class.addLayer ==> (index):614

```
geodjango_gps_point.map.addLayer(geodjango_gps_point.layers.vector);
```

geodjango_gps_point.init ==> (index):677 (anonymous function)

```
<script type="text/javascript">geodjango_gps_point.init();</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems were describ and sorry for the poor lisibility. So here some answers :

> 1 - The DateField and Timefield seems to be issued and this will be fix :

[Fix 168 (last update 3 days ago)](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped/issues/168)

> 2 - My PointField show up correctly after adding this options to settings.py :

```
DAB_FIELD_RENDERER = 'django_admin_bootstrapped.renderers.BootstrapFieldRenderer'
```

Thank's all